# Error while reading a Array from C# assembly registered as COM in VBScript

Tags: c#, vbscript, com

I have used the `xsd.exe` program to create a class hierarchy for a `xsd` file. I am successfully able to deserialize a xml file and read values from it in `C#`. However when i register the library and am trying to read array values from `VBScript` it fails.
I get `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment` error. I am however able to read the values of simple properties.

Here is my class hierarchy

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public partial class AppEntryDefinition {

    private ProductDefinition productDefinitionField;

    private ViewSection[] viewDefinitionField;

    public ProductDefinition productDefinition {
        get {
            return this.productDefinitionField;
        }
        set {
            this.productDefinitionField = value;
        }
    }

/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("viewSection", IsNullable=false)]
    public ViewSection[] viewDefinition {
        get {
            return this.viewDefinitionField;
        }
        set {
            this.viewDefinitionField = value;
        }
    }
}

public partial class ProductDefinition {

    private int kindCodeField;

    private string productCodeField;

    private string productTitleField;

    private string adminSystemField;

    private string vapCodeField;

    private Features featuresField;

    private RuleSet[] ruleSetField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int kindCode {
        get {
            return this.kindCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.kindCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string productCode {
        get {
            return this.productCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.productCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string productTitle {
        get {
            return this.productTitleField;
        }
        set {
            this.productTitleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string adminSystem {
        get {
            return this.adminSystemField;
        }
        set {
            this.adminSystemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string vapCode {
        get {
            return this.vapCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.vapCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Features features {
        get {
            return this.featuresField;
        }
        set {
            this.featuresField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ruleSet")]
    public RuleSet[] ruleSet {      
        get {
            return this.ruleSetField;
        }
        set {
            this.ruleSetField = value;
        }
    }
} 

public partial class RuleSet {

    private Rule[] ruleField;

    private string phaseField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("rule")]
    public Rule[] rule {
        get {
            return this.ruleField;
        }
        set {
            this.ruleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string phase {
        get {
            return this.phaseField;
        }
        set {
            this.phaseField = value;
        }
    }
} 

public partial class Rule {

    private Case[] caseField;

    private string nameField;

    private string typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("case")]
    public Case[] @case {
        get {
            return this.caseField;
        }
        set {
            this.caseField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type {
        get {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code which deserializes my xml to objects

```
namespace CustomUtilities
{
    public class XmlSerializer
    {
        public AppEntryDefinition Deserialize(String xmlPath)
        {

            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(AppEntryDefinition));
            AppEntryDefinition aed = null;
            aed = (AppEntryDefinition)serializer.Deserialize(new System.IO.StreamReader(xmlPath));
            return aed;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my vbscript code

```
Dim obj, objAppEntry
Set obj = CreateObject("CustomUtilities.XmlSerializer")
Set objAppEntry = obj.Deserialize("C:\Users\xx\Desktop\schema\xx.xml")
Set xxx = objAppEntry.productDefinition.ruleSet
```

Comment: Arrays may not cross the VBScript/COM <-> .NET interop layer easily, so that may be expected. Please post a specific piece of code so we may provide further help.

Comment: @SimonMourier  Please see sample code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these arrays will not get through from NET to VBScript as they are not [COM automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation) compatible.

What you can do, though, is create a partial class with the same name as the initial one, duplicate the array properties, give them another name, and declare them as a type that can be used in automation (and recompile the whole thing). You could create a custom type (it's necessary if yuo don't want to duplicate the values), but the easiest way to do it is to reuse the "old" [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) class. It's marked as COM visible and it can be used easily from a script language.

So here is a sample partial add-on:

```
public partial class ProductDefinition
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ArrayList ruleSetArrayList
    {
        get
        {
            return new ArrayList(ruleSet);
        }
    }     
}
```

And the script that uses it:

```
Set xxx = objAppEntry.productDefinition.ruleSetArrayList
for each item in xxx
    WScript.echo item.phase
next
```